HiBench running error hibench.hadoop.examples.jar not found
I'm trying to use Intel's HiBench to build workloads on gcp. I successfully managed to build the maven project and I did set the configurations as follow:
hadoop.conf:
# Hadoop home
hibench.hadoop.home     /usr/lib/hadoop

# The path of hadoop executable
hibench.hadoop.executable     ${hibench.hadoop.home}/bin/hadoop

# Hadoop configraution directory
hibench.hadoop.configure.dir  ${hibench.hadoop.home}/etc/hadoop

# The root HDFS path to store HiBench data
hibench.hdfs.master       hdfs://external-ip-adress-of-my-cluster:8020


# Hadoop release provider. Supported value: apache
hibench.hadoop.release    apache

spark.conf
whammouda@hibench-cluster-m:~/HiBench$ cat conf/spark.conf
# Spark home
hibench.spark.home      /usr/lib/spark

# Spark master
#   standalone mode: spark://xxx:7077
#   YARN mode: yarn-client
hibench.spark.master    spark://external-ip-adress-of-my-cluster:7077

# executor number and cores when running on Yarn
hibench.yarn.executor.num     2
hibench.yarn.executor.cores   4

# executor and driver memory in standalone & YARN mode
spark.executor.memory  4g
spark.driver.memory    4g

# set spark parallelism property according to hibench's parallelism value
spark.default.parallelism     ${hibench.default.map.parallelism}

# set spark sql's default shuffle partitions according to hibench's parallelism value
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions  ${hibench.default.shuffle.parallelism}

#======================================================
# Spark Streaming
#======================================================
# Spark streaming Batchnterval in millisecond (default 100)
hibench.streambench.spark.batchInterval          100

# Number of nodes that will receive kafka input (default: 4)
hibench.streambench.spark.receiverNumber        4

# Indicate RDD storage level. (default: 2)
# 0 = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY
# 1 = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
# other = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2
hibench.streambench.spark.storageLevel 2

# indicate whether to test the write ahead log new feature (default: false)
hibench.streambench.spark.enableWAL false

# if testWAL is true, this path to store stream context in hdfs shall be specified. If false, it can be empty (default: /var/tmp)
hibench.streambench.spark.checkpointPath /var/tmp

hibench.streambench.spark.useDirectMode true


When I run  bin/workloads/micro/wordcount/prepare/prepare.sh
I get this error:
"No files found under certain path(s), please set " + config_name + " manually"
AssertionError: No files found under certain path(s), please set hibench.hadoop.examples.test.jar manually
/home/whammouda/HiBench/bin/functions/workload_functions.sh: line 38: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
start HadoopPrepareWordcount bench
./prepare.sh: line 26: INPUT_HDFS: unbound variable
For information this is what the bash file looks like:
current_dir=`dirname "$0"`
current_dir=`cd "$current_dir"; pwd`
root_dir=${current_dir}/../../../../../
workload_config=${root_dir}/conf/workloads/micro/wordcount.conf
. "${root_dir}/bin/functions/load_bench_config.sh"

enter_bench HadoopPrepareWordcount ${workload_config} ${current_dir}
show_bannar start

rmr_hdfs $INPUT_HDFS || true
START_TIME=`timestamp`

run_hadoop_job ${HADOOP_EXAMPLES_JAR} randomtextwriter \
    -D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.totalbytes=${DATASIZE} \
    -D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.bytespermap=$(( ${DATASIZE} / ${NUM_MAPS} )) \
    -D mapreduce.job.maps=${NUM_MAPS} \
    -D mapreduce.job.reduces=${NUM_REDS} \
    ${INPUT_HDFS}
END_TIME=`timestamp`

show_bannar finish
leave_bench

I tried to set the enviroment variable ${HADOOP_EXAMPLES_JAR}to point towards a jar I downloaded from maven but I still got the same error. (There is no hadoop.examples.jar in the initial directory)

You INPUT_HDFS variable is not set. Try something like
set -u
...
rmr_hdfs "$INPUT_HDFS" || true
...


also, use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix other errors in your script.
